# How to I keep a .net framework error from popping up when my program can't connect to a server?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Just to be clear my question *isn't* why I am getting the .net framework error : But I posted the error just in case it helps someone understand my issue.

(System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server system.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)

*My question is* when I get this error how do I prevent a message from popping up with the error.  From time to time my program won't be able to connect to the remote server and that is ok in my situation.  I just don't want the error message to open if it can't connect.  Any suggestions on code I can use to stop this when it happens or prevent the error message from opening in the first place would be appreciated.  I am obviously new to developing and am using VB.net. I thought I could fix it with a try, catch, end try, but I must be using it wrong.  Thanks in advance.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net.IPAddress
Imports System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily
Imports System.Timers


Public Class eTicketBox
    Private Property IE As Object
    Private last_alert As String
    Private Property ip As String
    Dim input As String = "http://iticket.sstire.com/admin/xmlfeed2.php"
    Dim xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(input)
    Dim str As String = ""
    Dim str2 As String = ""

    Private Property strModified As String

    Private Sub eTicketBox_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load,           MyBase.Shown
        str = ""
    End Sub
    Private Sub TimerEventProcessor() Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Start()
        Call getAlert()

    End Sub
    Public Function getAlert() As Object

        alertTextBox.Text = ("Alert: " & vbNewLine & "There are no known alerts at this time.")
        'reads the xmlfeed
        Dim input As String = "http://blahblahxml.php"
        Dim xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(input)


        Do While xr.Read

            If xr.HasValue Then

                str = xr.Value.ToString
                alertTextBox.Text = ("Alert: " & vbNewLine & xr.Value.ToString)
                str2 = str

            End If
        Loop

    End Function

    Private Sub alertTextBox_TextChanged() Handles alertTextBox.TextChanged
        If str2 <> str Then
            Me.Show()
        End If`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed xr declaration, added its instantiation to the load event, and added a try..catch with the catch swallowing exceptions. I really don't like doing that, but it is quick and dirty.

```
Public Class eTicketBox
    Private Property IE As Object
    Private last_alert As String
    Private Property ip As String
    Dim input As String = "http://iticket.sstire.com/admin/xmlfeed2.php"
    Dim xr As XmlReader = nothing
    Dim str As String = ""
    Dim str2 As String = ""

    Private Property strModified As String

    Private Sub eTicketBox_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles MyBase.Load, MyBase.Shown

        xr = XmlReader.Create(input)
        str = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub TimerEventProcessor() Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Start()
        Call getAlert()
    End Sub

    Public Function getAlert() As Object
        Try
            alertTextBox.Text = "Alert: " & vbNewLine & _
                "There are no known alerts at this time."
            'reads the xmlfeed
            Dim input As String = "http://blahblahxml.php"
            Dim xr As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(input)

            Do While xr.Read
                If xr.HasValue Then
                    str = xr.Value.ToString
                    alertTextBox.Text = ("Alert: " & vbNewLine & xr.Value.ToString)
                    str2 = str
                End If
            Loop
        Catch ex As Exception
        End try
    End Function

    Private Sub alertTextBox_TextChanged() Handles alertTextBox.TextChanged
        If str2 <> str Then
            Me.Show()
        End If
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much...that worked.  I don't expect it to not to be able to connect to the remote server often but now if it does happen I don't have 200+ users calling the help desk because there was an error message popping up on their computers.  Much appreciated.